# stop player falling at start of game and use tap to start in unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a game for android in unity 5.3.5, when the scree is tapped the player moves upwards and have to keep tapping, however when the game starts the player falls down and out of play area! what i want to do is have the player stationary when game starts so when screen is tapped the game begins! here is the code..

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public string currentColor;

public float jumpForce = 10f;

public Rigidbody2D circle;
public SpriteRenderer sr;

public Color blue;
public Color yellow;
public Color pink;
public Color purple;

public static int score = 0;
public Text scoreText;

public GameObject obsticle;
public GameObject colorChanger;


void Start () {

    setRandomColor ();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

        if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 

        {
            circle.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        }

    scoreText.text = score.ToString ();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.tag == "Scored") 
    {
        score++;
        Destroy (collision.gameObject);
        Instantiate (obsticle, new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y + 7f), transform.rotation);
        return;
    }

    if (collision.tag == "ColorChanger") 
    {
        setRandomColor ();
        Destroy (collision.gameObject);
        Instantiate(colorChanger, new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y + 7f), transform.rotation);
        return;
    }

    if (collision.tag != currentColor) {
        Debug.Log ("You Died");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
        score = 0;
    }

    if (collision.tag == "Floor") 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
}

void setRandomColor()
{
    int rand = Random.Range (0, 4);

    switch (rand) 
    {
    case 0:
        currentColor = "Blue";
        sr.color = blue;
        break;

    case 1:
        currentColor = "Yellow";
        sr.color = yellow;
        break;

    case 2:
        currentColor = "Pink";
        sr.color = pink;
        break;

    case 3:
        currentColor = "Purple";
        sr.color = purple;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add a bool; `isFirstTouch`. Make it false t the beginning. Check it in update. When a touch is performed. Make it true. And if it is true then run your code ?

Comment: will try that, make isFirstTouch false in the start method you mean? then wrap the code in the update in another if statement?

Comment: Yes. You can make a new if statement with the bool, to wrap your current if block in update. Also you are using physics. You should change the `isKinematic` value like this bool as @ZayedUpal suggested.

Comment: player still seems to fall, i have made bool variable isFirstTouch, then set it to false in start method, also set circle.isKinematic = true; as @ZayedUpal mentioned, wrapped the code in the update in an if statemenet that says if isFirstTouch = true;

Comment: What happens when you set isKinematic = true in the editor before starting the game? Is it still falling when you start the game ?

Comment: think we getting there, isKinematic = true in the start does keep the player in place! when touch the player shoots up screen! just a case of figuring out the update method now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153679/discussion-between-emree-and-david-marsh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `circle.isKinematic = true;` at first.
On first tap make it to `circle.isKinematic = false;`

Comment: thank you to both of you and @EmreE for helping! greatly appreciated